# trace class norms of random matrices

Tags: matrices, probability-theory, random-matrices

We denote by $||.||_1$ the [trace class norm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) on $M_n$.Let $(r_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j\leq n}$ be a family of independent identically distributed random variables which take the values $-1$ and $1$ with equal probability.

Let $e_{ij}$ be the standard unit matrix of $M_n$. We define the random matrix
$$
A=\sum_{i,j=1}^n r_{ij}e_{ij}.
$$
I am interested by lower bounds of the quantities
$$
P\big(||A||_1<\alpha\mathbb{E}||A||_1\big)\ 
\text{ and } \ 
P\big(||A||_1>\beta\mathbb{E}||A||_1\big)
$$

where $\alpha, \beta>0$.

I would like obtain the existence of random matrices with $||.||_1$ far from 
the expectation (as far away as possible).

Any comment is welcome.

Remark 1: it seems to me that Szarek proved that 
$$
\mathbb{E}(||A||_1)=O(n^{3/2}).
$$

Remark 2: If $B$ is a matrix of $M_n$ such each entry of $B$ is 1 or -1 then 
$$
||B||_1\leq K_n
$$
where $K_n$ is a constant depending on the dimension $n$.